# Matrix multiplication in C returns unexpected results

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication

Well, here is some simple code to create a 3X3 matrix of ones and multiply the matrix by itself. 
I expect to see a square matrix 3X3 of threes. 
However the output is very different from what I expect. 
**I expect:**

`3 3 3
3 3 3
3 3 3`

**I get:**

`4 3 1530309563 
32770 76107779 4 
1764799051 32770 1530309579`

Any insight?
Thanks,
Anjan

Here is the code: `

```
int main()
{

    const int ROW = 3;
    const int COL= 3;
    int mat[ROW][COL];
    int mul[ROW][COL];

//create a matrix of ones
    for (int r=0; r<= ROW-1 ; r++)
    {
        for (int c=0; c<= COL-1; c++)
        {
            mat[r][c]=1;
        }
    }


    for (int r=0; r<= ROW -1; r++)
    {
        for (int c=0; c<= COL -1; c++)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<=COL-1; i++)
            {
                mul[r][c]+=mat[r][i]*mat[i][c];
            }
        }   
    }


    for (int r=0; r<= ROW -1 ; r++)
    {
        for (int c=0; c<= COL-1; c++)
        {
            printf("%d ",mul[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

`

Comment: Having different constants for rows and columns for multiplication is not a good idea ...

Comment: `r<= ROW - 1` (notice the spaces **around** `-`) is correct, but harder to read and error-prone. Use `r < ROW`.

Comment: @Olaf non-square matrices may be multiplied (although this code wouldn't handle that situation currently)

Comment: @M.M: Hmm, quite some time when I worked with matrices, but IIRC, that would actually basically result in making them square first. Or did I really miss something?

Comment: You can multiply PxQ matrix with QxR matrix to produce a PxR matrix.   Multiplying matrix by vector is a special case of this

Answer (score 3):

`mul` values aren't initialized so his values are unexpected.
Try adding this line in the initialization loop:

```
mul[r][c] = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you Admin XVII and M.M. Initializing mul[r][c] to 0 makes the code work as expected. I was under the impression that array elements, in C, are automatically initialized to 0, hmmmm.....

Answer (score 2):

You never initialized the `mul` array, so `mul[r][c]+=` adds onto garbage.

To fix this, after `mat[r][c] = 1;` put `mul[r][c] = 0;` .